# C++ string array about nums

Tags: c++, arrays, string

Say the strings is "Asah1234&^%736hsi)(91",
than storage 1234,736,91 in three arrays

In general,i want to put each continuous nums in each array.
Queations: how many arrays i will need,what's the size of each group of numbers,how to make the loop.
I want to write a fuction to do it.

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std;

void splitString(string str)
{
    string  num;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(str[i]))
            num.push_back(str[i]);
    }
    cout << num << endl;
}
int countnum( string str)
{
    string  num;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(str[i]))
            sum++;
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    const int MAXLEN = 100;
    char str[MAXLEN];
    printf("please enter strings:");
    scanf_s("%s", str, MAXLEN);
    splitString(str);
    countnum( str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The first thing you will need to do is post code that you have already tried, or show what your progress is. Most people here will not write your code from scratch for you.

Comment: Be clear with what you need, as this looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). For extracting the digits you can use `isdigit()` while checking your string character by character.

Comment: Please be more specific about your problem. What is stopping you from doing this? If your main problem is the size of the arrays, it's a good time to learn about [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Are you trying to parse and extract numbers from a string and put it into different arrays ?  You should check about regular expressions and how you can use them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have a misunderstanding here. Then please comment and I will delete the answer.

This is a standard task and will be solved with a regex. It is just the definition of a variable and initialzing this variable with its range constructor. So, a one-liner.

There is no further statement needed.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>

std::regex re{ R"(\d+)" };

int main() {

    // The input string with test data
    std::string test{"Asah123&^%736hsi)(918"};

    // Define a variable numbers and use the range constructor to put all data in it
    std::vector numbers(std::sregex_token_iterator(test.begin(), test.end(), re), {});

    // Show the result on the screen
    for (const auto& n : numbers) std::cout << n << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: actually i can't understand your code,i'm a fresh man,but thank you.